# Variable function name that points to a method

Tags: php, function, variables

For functions I can just assign the function name to a string variable, but how do I do it for class methods?

```
$func = array($this, 'to' . ucfirst($this->format));
$func(); // fails in PHP 5.3
```

This seems to work:

```
$this->{"to{$this->format}"}();
```

But it's way too long for me. I need to call this function many times...

Comment: Could you please clarify what member function you are trying to call and how you would call it without using a variable? It's hard to tell what is the function name and/or if there are any parameters based on your question.

Comment: I'm trying to access a non-static class method, eg. `$this->toHtml()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use php's [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php);

**Example:**

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'to' . ucfirst($this->format)), array());
```

You can also use the `self` keyword or the class name with the [scope resolution operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

**Example:**

```
$name = 'to' . ucfirst($this->format);
self::$name();

className::$name();
```

However, what you have posted using php's [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) is also completely valid:

```
$this->{"to{$this->format}"}();
```

`call_user_func_array()` is probably considered more readable than using variable functions, but from what I've read (like [here](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/182)), variable functions tend to out perform `call_user_func_array()`.

What did you mean by the variable function being **too long**?

Answer (score 1):

That's not really a function? Why don't use standard method for functions?

```
function func() {
$func = array($this, 'to' . ucfirst($this->format));
return $func;
}
```

then output it with

```
func();
```

Comment: Any variable string can be called as a function. Take a look at php [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) documentation.

Comment: Sorry, but according to the examples, calling a variable string as a function should be done this way: function func() { bblabla } $variable = 'func'; $variable() => so $variable() calls func()

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
class A
{

  function thisIsAwesome()
  {
    return 'Hello';
  }

}

$a = new A;

$awesome = 'IsAwesome';

echo call_user_func(array($a, 'this' . $awesome));
```

Although it's still quite long. You could write your own function to do it:

```
function call_method($a, $b)
{
  return $a->$b();
}

$a = new A;

$awesome = 'IsAwesome';

echo call_method($a, 'this' . $awesome);
```

Which is a litter shorter.